# req.session undefined in Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've seen several posts related to this but none solved my problem.

I have this code in server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.configure(function(){
    app.set(express.cookieParser());
        app.set(express.session({secret: "This is a secret"}));
});
app.get('/name/:name', function(req, res){
    req.session.name = req.params.name;
    res.send("<a href='/name'>GO</a>");
});
app.get('/name', function(req, res){
    res.send(req.session.name);
});
app.listen(3000);
```

When I go to `http://localhost:3000/user/someone` that's the output that I get
`TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined at /Users/Me/Node/server.js:10:19 at callbacks`

Comment: wasn't that `app.use(express.cookieParser())`, etc?

Comment: (also, I think `app.configure` is not needed and only kept as legacy, you should just call `app.use(stuff)`).

Comment: The `app.configure()` method is not legacy, and neither is it used incorrectly here. The issue here is that the person who asked the question is using the method used to set settings rather than the method to apply middleware.

Comment: The [docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.configure) seem to suggest it's legacy...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decided to copy from comments. Try replacing

```
app.configure(function(){
    app.set(express.cookieParser());
        app.set(express.session({secret: "This is a secret"}));
});
```

with

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({secret: "This is a secret"}));
```

and see what happens.