# req.session is undefined express-session

Tags: node.js, session, express, express-session

I know this question has been asked several times. However, none of the answers I've read has solved my question.

Many of them were outdated for express v4, as express-session is currently a separate module. Those question/answers are here:

- ['session' is undefined when using express / redis for session store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191692/session-is-undefined-when-using-express-redis-for-session-store)
- [req.session undefined in Express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608366/req-session-undefined-in-express-js)
- [nodejs express req.session undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489237/nodejs-express-req-session-undefined)

Other questions are updated, however the solution given doesn't fix my problem. Those question/answers are here:

- [NodeJS express-session req.session is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37138225/nodejs-express-session-req-session-is-undefined)
- [req.session is undefined using express-session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39796228/req-session-is-undefined-using-express-session)

Most of the solutions are the sequence of middlewares when configuring the app. I've tried different options and I doesn't find the correct way to do it. Maybe it's just that.

In other solution, someone says that `session` middleware cannot be called, because if it were, `req.session` would be defined. I've used middlewares just before an after `app.use(session({...}))`, and checked that both get called.

I've also found in [this issue](https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/4) someone saying that he gets `req.session` undefined when the store disconnects. I'm using the default store so far. Could this be the problem?

I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined

It breaks just when I try to logout a session with `req.session.destroy()` at login.js (see code below)

#### My code

***server.js***

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const mongo = require('mongodb');
const passport = require('passport');
const path = require('path');
const routes = require('./app/routes');
const login = require('./app/routes/login.js');

const app = express();
app.use(session({
  secret: 'key',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use('/public', express.static(path.normalize('./public')));
app.use(routes);
app.use(login);
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

const MongoClient = mongo.MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp')
.then((db) => {
  // Link the database through the app. It will be available in the req.app object
  app.db = db;
  console.log('App listening on port ' + process.env.PORT);
  app.listen(process.env.PORT);
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log('There was an error connecting to the database.');
  console.log(err);
});

module.exports = app; // For testing
```

***login.js***

```
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');
const router = new express.Router();

// Other login logic here

router.get('/logout', (res, req) => {
  req.session.destroy((err) => {
    req.redirect('/');
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You swapped the `req` and `res` arguments in your handler:

```
router.get('/logout', (res, req) => { ... })
```

That should be the other way around:

```
router.get('/logout', (req, res) => { ... })
```

Comment: Wooops! I can be really blind sometimes. After fixing the bug you discovered, I also realised that `req.redirect('/');` should be `res.redirect('/');`, but it was previously working because of the bug. It's like one bug was fixing the other. Thank you for the answer!